# Interpret / run a web page in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a JavaScript script that runs in Node.js (as a one-time command-line script, not as a long-lived server) that interfaces with the Spotify web API.

To be authorized to call Spotify endpoints, I must follow their workflow to obtain an authorization code that is in turn used to obtain an access token that I must supply in an http header for each API request.

I currently obtain the authorization code by opening a specific URL in a browser. The browser redirects a few times, with the final URL containing a `code` query param whose value is the authorization code.

I then copy the authorization code from the browser's address bar, then paste it as an argument to my command-line for the Node.js script. My Node.js script already automates obtaining the access token from the authorization code.

I want to automate the fetching of the authorization code in my script so I needn't manually obtain it from a browser to paste into the command line.

The authorization code workflow involves sending a static http get request to Spotify (the Get), which replies with a 303 redirect (the Redirect), which provides an html page that runs JavaScript (the Page) that then redirects via JavaScript (not via http redirect) to a URL with a `code` query parameter whose value is the newly issued authorization code.

I know how to read a 303 redirect in Node.js, and how to request that redirected page.

Is there any way for Node.js (either intrinsically or via third-party npm packages) to load the html page returned by the Redirect, run its JavaScript, and find the URL to which the JavaScript redirects? If so, I can then just read the `copy` query param from the URL to obtain my authorization code. Otherwise, I must reverse engineer the manner in which the Page JavaScript eventually generates the `code`, which would take some time, and would be brittle, as Spotify could change their code at any time. It would be simpler just to run the Page to get the `code`, if that's possible.

Comment: You could just run a full blown browser inside node,.  Have a look at pupperteer,  https://pptr.dev/   But this could still be brittle if Spotify changes the website.  Unfortunately if Spotify doesn't supply a direct way to do this it's always going to brittle.

Comment: Thanks. Puppeteer looks like it will do what I need.